# Input Redirection reading integers and char C++

Tags: c++, input, integer, character, io-redirection

Thanks for taking your time to read this!

I'm having trouble parsing through a file with input redirection and I am having trouble reading through integers and characters.

Without using getline(), how do you read in the file including integers, characters, and any amount of whitespaces? (I know the >> operator can skip whitespace but fails when it hits a character)

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code that you've written so far.

Comment: _"but fails when it hits a character"_ ??

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to realise is that, fundamentally, there are no things like "integers" in your file. Your file does not contain typed data: it contains *bytes*.

Now, since C++ doesn't support any text encodings, for our purposes here we can consider bytes equivalent to "characters". (In reality, you'll probably layer something like a UTF-8 support library on top of your code, at which point "characters" takes on a whole new meaning. But we'll save that discussion for another day.)

At the most basic, then, we can just extract a bunch of bytes. Let's say 50 at a time:

```
std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
static constexpr const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 50;
char buf[CHUNK_SIZE];

while (ifs.read(buf, CHUNK_SIZE)) {
   const size_t num_extracted = ifs.gcount();
   parseData(buf, num_extracted);
}
```

The function `parseData` would then examine those bytes in whatever manner you see fit.

For many text files this is unnecessarily arduous. So, as you've discovered, the IOStreams part of the C++ Standard Library provides us with some shortcuts. For example, `std::getline` will read bytes up to a delimiter, rather than reading a certain *quantity* of bytes.

Using this, we can read in things "line by line" — assuming a "line" is a sequence of bytes terminated by a `\n` (or `\r\n` if your platform performs line-ending translation, and you haven't put the stream into binary mode):

```
std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
static constexpr const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 50;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
   parseLine(line);
}
```

Instead of `\n` you can provide, as a third argument to `std::getline`, some other delimiter.

The other facility it offers is `operator<<`, which will pick out *tokens* (sequences of bytes delimited by whitespace) and attempt to "lexically cast" them; that is, it'll try to interpret friendly human ASCII text into C++ data. So if your input is "123 abc", you can pull out the "123" into an `int` with value `123`, and the `"abc"` into another string.

If you need more complex parsing, though, you're back to the initial offering, and to the conclusion of my answer: read everything and parse it byte-by-byte as you see fit. To help with this, there's [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) inherited from the C standard library, or [spooky incantations from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html); or you could just write your own algorithms.

The above is true of any compatible input stream, be it a `std::ifstream`, a `std::istringstream`, or the good old ready-provided `std::istream` instance named `std::cin` (which I guess is how you're accepting the data, given your mention of input redirection: shell scripting?).